# Pentaho Spoon Job Executes Fine, Endless Loop in Kitchen

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Without getting too much into the weeds, I have a Pentaho PDI job with multiple sub-transformations and sub-jobs (ETL from MySQL to Postgres). This job runs exactly as expected from Spoon, no errors, but when I run the job--with the following command--I am met with an endless loop error at the first step where a parameter would need to be defined and passed from within the job (the named params from the command seem to integrate fine). The command I am using is as follows:

```
sudo /bin/sh kitchen.sh \
-rep=KettleFileRepo \
-dir=M2P \
-job=ETL-M2P \
-level=Rowlevel \
-param:MY.PAR.LOADTYPE=full \
-param:MY.PAR.TABLELIST=table1 \
-param:MY.PAR.TENANTS=tenant1 \
/
```

Has anyone run into this type of issue with a discrepancy between Spoon and Kitchen? Is there some sort of config or command line option that I am missing? I am running version 6.0.1.0-386 on OS X 10.11.4.

If you think more details would be beneficial please let me know and I can provide whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any discrepancy between Spoon and Kitchen. Are you sure, its not something in the ETL that causing the loop. I would suggest to go through your ETL in detail.

Another thing you can try to debug is run only part of the job in kitchen and keep adding more as you see success.